# QlikView VBScript: Values selection by condition

Tags: vbscript, qlikview

There are two tables. Each table is in a separate list box.

If I select a value in the `YM` table, for example `2017 08`, `2017 07` or `2017 06`, then `2017 Q2` should automatically be selected in the `YQ` table.

If I choose `2016 12`, `2017 01` or `2017 02` in `YM` then `2016 Q3` should be selected in `YQ`, and so on for other years and quarters.

The common dependency is:

```
Month    | Quater
03,04,05 | Q1
06,07,08 | Q2
09,10,11 | Q3
12,01,02 | Q4
```

The script shoul be written in VBScript, and I'm confused how to do this as I am a total rookie in VBScript. Please, help me to understand.

```
LOAD * INLINE [
    YQ
    2017 Q3
    2017 Q2
    2017 Q1
    2016 Q4
    2016 Q3
    2016 Q2
    2016 Q1
    2015 Q4
    ..............
    2014 Q1
];


LOAD * INLINE [
    YM
    2017 11
    2017 10
    2017 09
    2017 08
    2017 07
    2017 06
    2017 05
    2017 04
    2017 03
    2017 02
    2017 01
    2016 12
    2016 11
    2016 10
    ............
    2014 01
];
```

Comment: looks like you need to use "triggers": http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Document_Properties_Triggers.htm

Comment: Guess you are right. Thanks for link.